# how to use "target" tag with an #id in Sass?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a problem with my code in sass.

In css my code is :

```
#slider-image-1:target ~ .s4-image-container;
```

but I don't know how I should write this is sass.

Comment: CSS is a valid SASS, so simply keep it like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ther are some different syntaxes in sass to write pseudo-codes. Hope this helps.

```
 #slider-image-1{
  &:target{
    ~ .s4-image-container{
      /* CSS code */
    }
  }
}
```